# Using @Remove to let the SFSB to be removed from bean container is not working for me

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

I am using Jobss 4.2.3 GA version and JRE 1.6. I am using a HttpSessionListener to handle sessionDestroyed() notification. In this method I invoke the @Remove method of a SFSB (which in turn invokes the @Remove method of another SFSB for which it has the reference). The SFSB beans have data in them (stored using HashMap). I clear this map in the @Remove method. After many sessions, I noticed that we are getting OOM error and I monitored the application using VisualVM and found that the SFSBs that were supposed to be cleaned up after session log out are infact still held in memory on most occations. I forced a full GC and they are still there. Any idea what could be the reason for this behavior?

Following is the code snippet I am using (changed class names to make more sense in the snippet) -

```
public class MTAppSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener
{
 public void sessionCreated( HttpSessionEvent event )
 {

 }

public void sessionDestroyed( HttpSessionEvent event )
 {
    HttpSession httpSession = event.getSession();       
     ServiceLocator locator = (ServiceLocator) httpSession.getAttribute("ServiceLocator");
     if(locator != null){   
        locator.removeService();            
     }
  } 
}

@Stateful
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "ServiceLocator/local")
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = "ServiceLocator/remote")
@SerializedConcurrentAccess
public class ServiceLocatorStatefulBean implements ServiceLocator, ServiceLocatorLocal, ServiceLocatorRemote 
{
     MTService service; // holds ref to another Stateful session bean.
     ...

 @Remove
private void removeService() {
    if (service != null) {
        service.remove(); // invoke its @Remove method
     }
 } 
}

@Stateful
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "MTService/local")
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = "MTService/remote")
@SerializedConcurrentAccess
public class MTServiceStatefulBean implements MTService, MTServiceLocal, MTServiceRemote 
{
        HashMap dataMap;

      @Remove
     private void remove() {
         if (dataMap != null) {
          dataMap.clear();
         }
  } 
}
```

web.xml (part) -

```
<web-app>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.myorg.mt.webapp.common.MTAppSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,
yvp